# Why is there space under the image in this code?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, and it allows the red to show through from the a element. Why is this. I would have expected that the a element would only expand to the size of the contents but it looks like it's a bit bigger than that. See the codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/soqEz.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a>
```

**CSS**

```
a{
  background: red;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  border-bottom:0;
}
img {
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  border-bottom:0;
}
```

**EDIT: I see the answers below ... but can anyone also explain *why* the space is there AT ALL ( I mean given that it's a block level element ... what's the purpose of it in the first place ) ... as opposed to trying to get rid of it. Thanks**

Comment: Given your question edit, the reason is explained in the accepted answers of the two linked questions in the above comments by @Quentin and myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `img` element is `inline` by default.  `inline` elements act as text and default to a `vertical-align: baseline`.  This means that the bottom of the image aligns with the bottom of your text.  Notice that a lower case p or g goes below the bottom of the vertical text alignment.  You can fix it by either adding `vertical-align: bottom` OR `display: block`.

Comment: Images are inline-block by default, not inline.

Comment: @cimmanon my browser is defaulting it to `inline`.  Source for inline-block?

Comment: Inline elements don't honor properties like margin, height, or width, while inline-* elements do.

Comment: @cimmanon - No, they are "replaced inline" not "inline-block". "inline-block" boxes have an internal structure that can affect the baseline of the box, "replaced inline" have opaque internals, but will otherwise honour the properties you mention, similar to  "inline-block" and not like "non-replaced inline" which don't.

Comment: See, for example how in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins, the width property handling requirements are very different for replaced and non-replaced inline boxes.

Answer (score 3):

It does this because it's an inline element. Change the display type

```
img {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because the image is an `inline` element by default. Add `display: block` to your `img` rule and see.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to add display:block, but to the image tag instead of the link tag.
add

```
img
{
display:block;
}
```